# ReactJS - I have to click twice on table row

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Begginner with React and JavaScript here.

I have 2 tables: headers and items. When I click on headers table row, only belonging items show in second table. This works fine, but when I need to use values from items I always get values from last click.

[console.log example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJL7U.png) For better understanding of the image, first header has 3 belonging items, second header has 2 belonging items.

So it works fine with rendering data in items table, but values in states are wrong. I understand that `this.setState` works in an asynchronous way and I have read about callback funtion which I am trying to use (console.log) but values in state are still wrong (late). I'm doing something wrong and I need help:

I'm using arrays in `this.state = { headers: [], items: [] };`

This is the way I get items:

```
getItems = async key => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:4000/putnistavke?pnal_z_id=${key}`
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  this.saveState(data);
};

saveState = data => {
  this.setState({ items: data.data }, console.log(this.state.items));
};
```

And this is the way I call onMouseUp event on table row:

```
{this.state.headers.map(header => (
  <tr key={header.id} onMouseUp={() => this.getItems(header.id)}>
    <td>{header.broj}</td>
    <td>{header.odjel}</td>
  </tr>
)}
```

Code for items rendering:

```
{this.state.items.map(items => (
 <tr key={items.id}>
 <td>{items.naziv_troska}</td>
 <td>{items.jmj}</td>
 <td>{items.kolicina}</td>
```

Comment: Your callback **function** should be a function, that is, `() => console.log(this.state.items)`. Also, can't you use `onClick` rather than `onMouseUp`?

Comment: Where is the code of items rendering

Comment: Thank you Kobe, it works fine now.

Comment: onMouseUp was used for testing, now it is changed to onClick. Code for items rendering is in question now @DmitryReutov